# How to get "individual cart items from a column" in the database using Gloudemans Shopping Cart

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel, shopping-cart

I am using **Gloudemans Shopping Cart package** and trying to get "individual cart items from a **cart** column" in the database, like '**name, price, qty**', but for some reasons when I do:

```
{{ $order['cart]['name'] }}
```

I get an error saying: *Illegal string offset 'name'*

But if I do :

```
{{ $order['cart'] }}
```

I get the whole cart item: `{"027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da":{"rowId":"027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da","id":1,"name":"web development","qty":1,"price":70,"weight":1,"options":[],"discount":0,"tax":0,"subtotal":70},"370d08585360f5c568b18d1f2e4ca1df":{"rowId":"370d08585360f5c568b18d1f2e4ca1df","id":2,"name":"graphics","qty":1,"price":100,"weight":1,"options":[],"discount":0,"tax":0,"subtotal":100}}`

Please, how do I solve this?

**Here are my files:**

**CheckoutController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\AccountOrder;
use Cart;

class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    public function myOrder($id)
    {
        $orders = auth()->user()->orders;
        return view('frontend/academic/myOrder')
        ->with('orders', $orders);
    }
}
```

**ShoppingController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;
use App\AccountOrder;
use Cart;

class ShoppingController extends Controller
{
    //function to add course to cart
    public function add_to_cart(Request $request, $pid)
    {
            
            
            $product = Category::findOrFail($pid);
                                                   
                //  insert into cart
                $cart = Cart::add([
                    'id' => $product->id,
                    'name' => $product->name,
                    'price' => $product->price,
                    'qty' => 1,
                    'weight' => 1,
                ]);

                if(route('cart.success', $pid))                   
                {
                    if($request->status === 'successful')
                    {
                        $data = auth()->user()->orders()->create([
                            'cart' => Cart::content(),
                            'transaction_id' => $request->transaction_id,
                            'status' => $request->status
                        ]);

                        //Cart::destroy();
                        dd($data);
                        return view('frontend/academic/success');
                    }

                }
            return redirect('cart');

    }
}
```

**myOrder.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.front');

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row medium-padding120 bg-border-color">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="order">
                <h2 class="h1 order-title text-center">My Order</h2>
                @foreach ($orders as $order)
                <div class="card mb-5">
                    <div class="card-header bg-info">
                        Purchased Date: {{$order->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                //Here is my Problem
                                {{$order['cart']['name']}}  {{$order['cart']['price']}}
                                <span class="badge"></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer bg-info">
                        <?php $variable = $order->cart ?>
                         //Here is also my Problem
                        <strong>Total Price: {{ $order['cart']['subtotal'] }} </strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a second `@foreach` to iterate through the order's cart:

```
@foreach ($order['cart'] as $cartItem)
   <li class="list-group-item">
     {{$cartItem->name}}  {{$cartItem->price}}
     <span class="badge"></span>
   </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but got this error:  "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@foreach` for individual cart item

```
@foreach ($order['cart'] as $key=>$cart)
    <li class="list-group-item">
        {{$cart->name}}  {{$cart->price}}
        <span class="badge"></span>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but got this error:  "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"